# Renames files with special characters using os.rename()

Tags: python, rename

In Python, I am trying to rename a number of files which names look like this:

B-4¨íÐóµ(602).dbf

Let's say this is the first element of the 'file_list' is my directory:

```
file_list = os.listdir(mydir)
file_list[0]

'B-4???\xa8?\xed\x8d\xd0\x8f\xf3?\xb5(602).dbf'
```

Now this is quite different from the name of the file as seen in windows explorer (above), which is probably the root of the issue following:

```
os.rename(file_list[0],'myfile.dbf')
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Any ideas on how I could rename this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your file contains non-ASCII characters, which cannot be represented correctly with ordinary Python (byte) strings. You can obtain the correct Unicode name from Python by passing a Unicode directory name to `listdir`; this will cause `listdir` to return Unicode filenames.

Example:

```
file_list = os.listdir(unicode(mydir)) # or e.g. mydir.decode('utf8')

os.rename(file_list[0], u'myfile.dbf')
```